# ImportError: No module named keras.preprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Following the tutorial:

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/08/10/imagenet-classification-with-python-and-keras/#comment-419896

Using these files:

```
 https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models
```

I get 2 separate errors depending on how I execute:

Running in PyCharm:

```
 Using TensorFlow backend.
 usage: test_imagenet.py [-h] -i IMAGE
 test_imagenet.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

Running in cmd line:

```
     C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts>python deep-learning-models/test_imagenet.py --image deep-learning-models/images/dog.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep-learning-models/test_imagenet.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.preprocessing import image as image_utils
ImportError: No module named keras.preprocessing
```

How do I resolve?

Comment: Keras Preprocessing is compatible with Python 2.7-3.6 if you don't know exactly how to fix it.
Using "colab" is a best choice xDD

Answer (score 3):

Its best if you solve this problem outside running the above script... Here is what you can try in your command line environment to make sure it works outside your script:

```
>>> import keras
    Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> keras.__version__
    '1.2.1'
>>> keras.preprocessing
    <module 'keras.preprocessing' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/__init__.pyc'>
>>> from keras.preprocessing import image as image_utils
>>>
```

Make sure you have latest version of keras installed. If you get above working then it could be the environment issue where above script is not able to find the keras package. However if above does not work or work partially you would need to install keras again by removing it first..

```
$ pip install keras --user
```

Answer (score 1):

Every dependency in a python project need to be installed using `pip` or `easy_install` or from the source code. You will have to install the keras module as mentioned [here](https://keras.io/#installation).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. It turned out I was working in a pyvenv which wasn't activated. Just run `source bin/activate` on Linux/Mac or `Scripts\activate.bat` on Windows

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras  import legacy_tf_layer
from keras.preprocessing import image as image_utils
from keras.preprcessing.text import Toknizer
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_spli
```

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you added an explanation. Use [edit] to enhance the answer.